# How to get 3 integers value in a single array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 3 intergers a,b,c and have values for them as 2,4,5 respectively.. how to store the 3 numbers in a `array int[] stats = new int[3];` in c#

and I have to add that value to a string and the output should be like

string val =[2,4,5];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] stats = {2,4,5};
```

or

```
int[] stats = new int[3];
stats[0] = a;
stats[1] = b;
stats[2] = c;
```

Answer (score 8):

Do you just mean:

```
int[] stats = { a, b, c };
```

? Alternatively, as per comments:

```
var stats = new[] { a, b, c };
```

or

```
var stats = new int[] { a, b, c };
```

Comment: +1 because I was still using `new[] { }`... Ah... but with the `new[]` you can use `var`... Interesting. Perhaps you could add this second "way".

Answer (score 1):

Or do you mean:

```
int[] stats = new int[3];
stats[0] = a;
stats[1] = b;
stats[2] = c;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

you can also store as follows

```
stats[0] = a;
stats[1] = b;
stats[2] = c;
```